# Remove "Fields" column from DocuSign UI

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to permanently remove the "Fields" column from the DocuSign form shown here:

[image]

I feel like the behavior here is spotty. Sometimes when I'm testing, I get this column where the user can drag and drop these fields. Other times, I get what I want, which is to just have the one "Sign" tab and a pre-filled date. I have looked high and low and cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a signer sees these icons to drag/drop, then you are in 'free form signing'. This happens when the sender does not designate/assign any tabs to the recipient.

In order to avoid this, ensure that the recipient has at least one DocuSign tab assigned.